# How to give more importance to one class within a batch when training the model

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, backwards-compatibility

I have five classes to train and would like one of my models to prioritize class 3 when training, so that the class 3 can get higher accuracy when predicting, how could I code that in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't matter as the addition operator is *commutative*.